# GradientDescentOptimizer got wrong result

Tags: tensorflow

**I want use gradient descent to solve equation set, but I got wrong result everytime, so I check my code and written a numpy edition, in this edition I provide explicit loss gradient and I can get currect result.**

So I don't understand why GradientDescentOptimizer can not work.

**here is my code without tf:**

```
import numpy as np


class SolveEquation:
    def __init__(self, rate: float, loss_threshold: float=0.0001, max_epochs: int=1000):
        self.__rate = rate
        self.__loss_threshold = loss_threshold
        self.__max_epochs = max_epochs
        self.__x = None

    def solve(self, coefficients, b):
        _a = np.array(coefficients)
        _b = np.array(b).reshape([len(b), 1])
        _x = np.zeros([_a.shape[1], 1])
        for epoch in range(self.__max_epochs):
            grad_loss = np.matmul(np.transpose(_a), np.matmul(_a, _x) - _b)
            _x -= self.__rate * grad_loss
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                loss = np.mean(np.square(np.subtract(np.matmul(_a, _x), _b)))
                print('loss = {:.8f}'.format(loss))
                if loss < self.__loss_threshold:
                    break
        return _x

s = SolveEquation(0.1, max_epochs=1)
print(s.solve([[1, 2], [1, 3]], [3, 4]))
```

**And here is my code with tf:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class TFSolveEquation:
    def __init__(self, rate: float, loss_threshold: float=0.0001, max_epochs: int=1000):
        self.__rate = rate
        self.__loss_threshold = tf.constant(loss_threshold)
        self.__max_epochs = max_epochs
        self.__session = tf.Session()
        self.__x = None

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.__session.close()
        finally:
            pass

    def solve(self, coefficients, b):
        coefficients_data = np.array(coefficients)
        b_data = np.array(b)
        _a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        _b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        _x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([coefficients_data.shape[1], 1]))
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.matmul(_a, _x) - _b))
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.__rate)
        model = optimizer.minimize(loss)
        self.__session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(self.__max_epochs):
            self.__session.run(model, {_a: coefficients_data, _b: b_data})
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                if self.__session.run(loss < self.__loss_threshold, {_a: coefficients_data, _b: b_data}):
                    break
        return self.__session.run(_x)

s = TFSolveEquation(0.1, max_epochs=1)
print(s.solve([[1, 2], [1, 3]], [3, 4]))
```

I test these 2 codes with very simple equation set:

```
x_1 + 2 * x_2 = 3
x_1 + 3 * x_3 = 4

loss = 1/2 * || Ax - b ||^2

Init x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, rate = 0.1
```

**Use gradient descent**
**So at 1st compute, the delta x = (0.7, 1.8)**

But unfortunately my code with tf give the

```
delta x = 
[[ 0.69999999]
 [ 1.75      ]]
```

And my code without tf give the

```
delta x = 
[[ 0.7]
 [ 1.8]]
```

**Absolutely code without tf is right, but why tf comput gradient may less 0.05 then currect result?**
**I think this is the reason my code without tf can solve the equation set, but tf edition can not solve equation set currently.**

**Can someone tell me why tf give a incurrent gradiant? Thanks**

My platform is Win10 + tensorflow-gpu v1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reshape `_b` in your tensorflow implementation. So you are subtracting a row from a column at this line:         `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.matmul(_a, _x) - _b))`.

**EDIT**: do not use reduce operations (such a mean or sum) without specifying a reduction axis. By default,  reduction operations in numpy and tensorflow reduce along all dimensions, so you keep getting a single number regardless dimensions of the input array. That could lead to many obscure bugs like that one.